# Arch single-GPU KVM passthrough goes back to login when booting VM

Tags: arch-linux, qemu, linux-kvm

Alright, so I made my KVM setup according to this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUSrdUoedTo
I'm running with an AsRock Fatal1ty motherboard, and an RTX 2060.
Whenever I boot my VM, it goes to the BIOS screen for 10 seconds as it's supposed to, but then just takes me back to Gnome's login screen.
I genuinely have no idea what to do, but I wanna switch to using Arch and gaming VMs.
It's my second day with Arch, so I'm still figuring it out

Here's the crashlog

Jun 25 23:04:59 asteroid libvirtd[23365]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
Jun 25 23:05:12 asteroid libvirtd[23365]: Unable to read from monitor: Connection reset by peer
Jun 25 23:05:12 asteroid libvirtd[23365]: internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: 2021-06-25T23:05:10.622006Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: This feature depends on other features that were not requested: CPUID.8000000AH:EDX.svme-addr-chk [bit 28]
2021-06-25T23:05:10.622707Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: This feature depends on other features that were not requested: CPUID.8000000AH:EDX.svme-addr-chk [bit 28]
2021-06-25T23:05:10.623094Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: This feature depends on other features that were not requested: CPUID.8000000AH:EDX.svme-addr-chk [bit 28]
2021-06-25T23:05:12.611634Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device vfio-pci,host=0000:10:00.0,id=hostdev0,bus=pci.5,addr=0x0,romfile=/home/downloads/patch.rom: Failed to mmap 0000:10:00.0 BAR 3. Performance may be slow
2021-06-25T23:05:12.628793Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device vfio-pci,host=0000:10:00.0,id=hostdev0,bus=pci.5,addr=0x0,romfile=/home/downloads/patch.rom: failed to find romfile "/home/downloads/patch.rom"
Jun 25 23:05:13 asteroid libvirtd[23365]: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2021-06-25T23:05:10.622006Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: This feature depends on other features that were not requested: CPUID.8000000AH:EDX.svme-addr-chk [bit 28]
2021-06-25T23:05:10.622707Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: This feature depends on other features that were not requested: CPUID.8000000AH:EDX.svme-addr-chk [bit 28]
2021-06-25T23:05:10.623094Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: This feature depends on other features that were not requested: CPUID.8000000AH:EDX.svme-addr-chk [bit 28]
2021-06-25T23:05:12.611634Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device vfio-pci,host=0000:10:00.0,id=hostdev0,bus=pci.5,addr=0x0,romfile=/home/downloads/patch.rom: Failed to mmap 0000:10:00.0 BAR 3. Performance may be slow
2021-06-25T23:05:12.628793Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device vfio-pci,host=0000:10:00.0,id=hostdev0,bus=pci.5,addr=0x0,romfile=/home/downloads/patch.rom: failed to find romfile "/home/downloads/patch.rom"